# Laplace transform of product of two unknown functions.

Tags: analysis

Find Laplace transform of $x(t)y(t)$, $X(s)$ and $Y(s)$ are the laplace transform of $x$ and $y$. Is there any method to find the transform of there product.

Comment: Not an exact duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12368/what-is-the-fourier-transform-of-the-product-of-two-functions , but same answer. I suggest marking as duplicate, given how similar Fourier and Laplace transforms are.

Comment: It's not simple in general, but with some cases you can use the definition  $\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-st}x(t)y(t)dt$